# Can I sort with Firebase Firestore child with the Python SDK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore with data structured as per below but am having issues being able to sort by a child.

```
{
    'agreement' : 'ALR87HJLKJJ78954',
    'agreementDetails' : {
        'name' : 'johnny5isalive',
        'country' : 'Spain'
    }
}
```

My query looks like the following:

```
query = db.collection('rentalAgreements').where('agreement', '==', agreement_number).order_by('/agreementDetails/name', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING).limit(10)
results = query.get()
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Path /agreementDetails/name not consumed, residue:
>   /agreementDetails/name

I did think I was chancing it a bit and found through Google a number of references to order_by_child which I also tried but it came back with an error:

> AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'order_by_child'

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing an object property, you will need to use dot notation in the field path:

```
query = db.collection('rentalAgreements')
    .where('agreement', '==', agreement_number)
    .order_by('agreementDetails.name', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING)
    .limit(10)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you Doug - Spent the last 30 minutes Googling for this.. worked a treat!  There needs to be a gift beer tokens button...